# How to handle iOS purchases for user-generated content?

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway

In my fitness application, there are two types of users, coaches, and trainees.

Coaches create fitness programs (they decide the price and duration), and then trainees buy those programs.

Problem is that Apple insists on using In App Purchase API - but I can't create the "packages" there since duration and price is not pre-determined by the developer.

One suggestion I saw is creating virtual currency in app, but I'm wondering would Apple allow embeding web browser with a payment form (Braintree)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would Apple allow embeding web browser with a payment form
>   (Braintree)?

No that's specifically against the guidelines.

You could create a virtual currency and purchase X amount for a specific in-app purchase (like games do).

Or create 10 already priced packages and let the coaches pick from those.